Failure when updating database
After running update-database, I got this error
PM> update-database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
Applying migration '20240403225657_InitialMigration'.
Failed executing DbCommand (44ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [Développeurs] (
    [ID_Développeur] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Nom_Développeur] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
    [ID_Projet] int NOT NULL,
    [IsM] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT CAST(0 AS bit),
    [ID_Planning] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Développeurs] PRIMARY KEY ([ID_Développeur]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Développeurs_Plannings_ID_Planning] FOREIGN KEY ([ID_Planning]) REFERENCES [Plannings] ([ID_Planning]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Développeurs_Projets_ID_Projet] FOREIGN KEY ([ID_Projet]) REFERENCES [Projets] ([ID_Projet]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Développeurs_Projets_ID_Projet' on table 'Développeurs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:32566a8f-df7d-4889-9bb2-48bef4f43474
Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Développeurs_Projets_ID_Projet' on table 'Développeurs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I tried adding .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction); - it didn't change anything.
Here is my code:
Projets.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Projet.Models
{
    public class Projets
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID_Projet { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Nom_Projet { get; set; }

        public string Description_Projet { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Version_Projet { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Révision_Projet { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Statut_Projet { get; set; }

        public List<Développeurs> Développeurs { get; } = new List<Développeurs>();

        public Plannings? Plannings { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Environnements> Environnements { get; } = new List<Environnements>();
        public List<BDDs> BDDs { get; } = new List<BDDs>();
        public ICollection<Languages> Languages { get; } = new List<Languages>();
        public List<Sites> Sites { get; } = new List<Sites>();
        public List<Toolboxes> Toolboxes { get; } = new List<Toolboxes>();


    }
}

Développeurs.cs
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Projet.Models
{
    public class Développeurs
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID_Développeur { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Nom_Développeur { get; set; }

        public int ID_Projet { get; set; }

        public Projets Projet { get; set; } // Navigation property

        public bool IsM { get; set; } // Discriminator

        public int ID_Planning { get; set; }

        public Plannings Plannings { get; set; } = null;
    }
}

ProjetContext.cs
//using System.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Projet.Models;

namespace Projet
{
    public class ProjetContext : DbContext
    {

        public ProjetContext()
        {

        }

        public ProjetContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }


        public DbSet<BDDs> BDDs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Développeurs> Développeurs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Environnements> Environnements { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Languages> Languages { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Plannings> Plannings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Projets> Projets { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sites> Sites { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Toolboxes> Toolboxes { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Projet;TrustServerCertificate=True;");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Développeurs>()
    .HasOne(d => d.Projet)
    .WithMany(p => p.Développeurs)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_Projet)
    .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Développeurs>()
                .Property(d => d.IsM)
                .HasDefaultValue(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Plannings>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Développeurs)
               .WithOne(e => e.Plannings)
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Planning).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Plannings)
                .WithOne(e => e.Projets)
                .HasForeignKey<Projets>(e => e.ID_Projet).IsRequired();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Environnements)
               .WithOne(e => e.Projets)
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Projet)
               .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
                .HasMany(e => e.BDDs)
                .WithMany(e => e.Projets)
                .UsingEntity<ProjetsBDDs>(
                    l => l.HasOne<BDDs>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_BDD),
                    r => r.HasOne<Projets>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Projet));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
               .HasMany(e => e.Languages)
               .WithOne(e => e.Projets)
               .HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Projet)
               .IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Sites)
                .WithMany(e => e.Projets)
                .UsingEntity<ProjetsSites>(
                    l => l.HasOne<Sites>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Site),
                    r => r.HasOne<Projets>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Projet));
            modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
                .HasMany(e => e.Toolboxes)
                .WithMany(e => e.Projets)
                .UsingEntity<ProjetsTools>(
                    l => l.HasOne<Toolboxes>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Toolbox),
                    r => r.HasOne<Projets>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(e => e.ID_Projet));
 }

    }


}

Migration script
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Projet.Migrations
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public partial class InitialMigration : Migration
    {
        /// <inheritdoc />
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Projets",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID_Projet = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        Nom_Projet = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        Description_Projet = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        Version_Projet = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        Révision_Projet = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        Statut_Projet = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Projets", x => x.ID_Projet);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Projets_Plannings_ID_Projet",
            column: x => x.ID_Projet,
            principalTable: "Plannings",
            principalColumn: "ID_Planning",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Développeurs",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID_Développeur = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        Nom_Développeur = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
        ID_Projet = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        IsM = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false, defaultValue: false),
        ID_Planning = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Développeurs", x => x.ID_Développeur);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Développeurs_Plannings_ID_Planning",
            column: x => x.ID_Planning,
            principalTable: "Plannings",
            principalColumn: "ID_Planning",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Développeurs_Projets_ID_Projet",
            column: x => x.ID_Projet,
            principalTable: "Projets",
            principalColumn: "ID_Projet",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
    name: "IX_Développeurs_ID_Projet",
    table: "Développeurs",
    column: "ID_Projet");
/// <inheritdoc />
protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Projets");

            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Développeurs");

            
        }
    }
}

Appreciate any help.

The solution is to specify the property in the migration script :
table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Développeurs_Projets_ID_Projet",
                        column: x => x.ID_Projet,
                        principalTable: "Projets",
                        principalColumn: "ID_Projet",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);

and then enter the command update-database in the 'PACKAGE MANAGER CONSOLE'

Due to the error here:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Développeurs_Projets_ID_Projet' on table 'Développeurs' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

You will have to specify the property as on delete no action or on update no action. You can do that through the context as such:
    modelBuilder.Entity<Projets>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Plannings)
    .WithOne(e => e.Projets)
    .OnDelete(/*DELETE BEHAVIOR HERE*/); 


I still get the same error even after specifying properties.

I have had this issue in the past when specifying properties' relationships multiple times, where did you specify the ondelete and on update specification?

I added the Migration script if you want to check it.

I specified it in 'modelBuilder.Entity<Développeurs>().HasOne(d => d.Projet).WithMany(p => p.Développeurs).HasForeignKey(d => d.ID_Projet).IsRequired()..OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);' But nothing changed and I deleted It.

Did you remove your previous migration and recreate it?

No. The migration was automatically created by the EF.Core
